# Conditional entropies of sum relations

Tags: probability-theory, entropy

Let $(X_1,Y_1)$ and $(X_2,Y_2)$ be identically and independently distributed. Also consider $Z=X_1+X_2$. I am trying to prove the following inequality:

$$ H(X_2 \vert Y_1 Y_2 Z) \leq H (X_1 \vert Y_1)\leq  H(Z \vert Y_1 Y_2).$$

I think I can show that middle term is the average of the other two. So now if I can show
$$ H(X_2 \vert Y_1 Y_2 Z) \leq  H(Z \vert Y_1 Y_2),$$ I should be done. Can someone give a hint?

Comment: Can you show that $H(X_2|X_1+X_2) \leq H(X_1+X_2)$?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus No. I don't see how to that. Or for that matter, I don't know if I can later add $Y_1, Y_2$ to it. I think you will later want to use $H(A) \leq H(B)$ implies $H(A \vert C) \leq H(B \vert C)$. I don't particularly see how to use their IID-ness.

Comment: The inequality you mention in the comment isn’t true in general. Consider for example $B=C$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes that's why I said that I don't see how your hint can lead to the required inequality. But in either case, I am unable to prove your hint also.

Comment: It’s not a hint. It’s a special case of what you need to prove. For example, $Y_1,Y_2$ could be constant. I suggest starting with this case since it is simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X_1,X_2$ are independent,
$$
H(X_1+X_2) \geq H(X_1+X_2|X_1) = H(X_2),
$$
and similarly $H(X_1+X_2) \geq H(X_1)$.
Therefore
$$
H(X_2|X_1+X_2) + H(X_1+X_2) = H(X_2,X_1+X_2) = H(X_1,X_2) \leq \\ H(X_1) + H(X_2) \leq 2H(X_1+X_2),
$$
which implies that
$$
H(X_2|X_1+X_2) \leq H(X_1+X_2).
$$
Since we have only used the independence of $X_1,X_2$ in this argument, we also have
$$
H(X_2|X_1+X_2,Y_1Y_2=y_1y_2) \leq H(X_1+X_2,Y_1Y_2=y_1y_2),
$$
since given $Y_1Y_2=y_1y_2$, the random variables $X_1,X_2$ just become arbitrary independent random variables. Taking expectation over $y_1,y_2$, we deduce
$$
H(X_2|X_1+X_2,Y_1,Y_2) \leq H(X_1+X_2|Y_1,Y_2).
$$